# Access current id for a has_one relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, has-one

I have two models in my app. One is called meetings and the other is outcome. I wanted to create the outcome of each meeting using: `@outcome=current_meeting.outcome.build(params[:outcome])`. Further, each meeting would have only one outcome so it is clearly a `has_one` relationship. I am really confused about getting the current_meeting. I have the meetings and outcomes models as:

**Meeting Model**

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :info, :meeting_date, :name, :venue
  has_many :participants, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :outcome, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_presence_of :name, :info, :meeting_date, :venue
end
```

**Outcome Model**

```
class Outcome < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :result
  belongs_to :meeting
  validates :meeting_id, presence: true
end
```

I want the new outcome to be present inside the show of the meeting, if there are none present and if there is one present creating new outcome should be made impossible

**meetings/show.html.erb**

```
<% if @meeting.outcomes.any? %>
   <%= render @outcomes %>
<% else %>
   <%= link_to "Add the outcome of meeting", new_outcome_path %>
<% end %>
```

My controllers are:

**Meetings controller**

```
def show
  @meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])
  @outcomes = @meeting.outcomes.all
end
```

**Outcomes controller**

```
def new
  @outcome = current_meeting.microposts.new
end

def create
  @outcome = current_meeting.outcomes.build(params[:outcome])
  if @outcome.save
    flash[:success] = "Outcome created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

I don't know how to find out the current_meeting. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the question is very confusing as to the plurality of `outcome` vs `outcomes`. If a Meeting has_one Outcome then you you would use the singular form when referring to the reference. Basically, given `has_one :outcome`, ":outcome" is the method name to be used. So you'd say `meeting.outcome` instead of `meeting.outcomes`. And the build method for [has_one](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one) would be like `meeting.build_outcome` instead of `meeting.outcomes.build`. The latter is the api for a [has_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) relationship.

With that out of the way, if you want to get the current Meeting from the Outcomes controller, the best way to do this is with nested resources. So in the routes file you'd have, e.g.:

```
resources :meetings do
  resources :outcomes
end
```

After you do that, run `rake routes` to see the routes available to you. In there you'll see an expected url format of `POST /meetings/:id/outcomes` which you would use here. So in this case, the `create` method would get the Meeting object from `params[:id]`, from which the outcome relationship can be created.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it does not seem like you are defining current_meeting anywhere. You probably already know this and if so the case would be that you are unsure of how/where to define it. You will probably need to do that somewhere in the code. This could mean saying something like this meeting is current because it is during the current time and/or today. This is based on how your app works to determine this logic.

In your controller or in a helper you will need to write a method that gives you the current meeting if one exists. From there the current_meeting variable in your controller will be set correctly and should call your other methods right.

If I have misunderstood the issue I apologize and please provide any other details you can and I can try to help.